# how to move the text to the left

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How do I move the highlighted text to left-hand side? Ah, I am so tired trying to adjust this and seeing undesirable results. Can anyone please help?

[image: screenshot]

### HTML

```html
<div mat-dialog-actions class="actionButtons">
  <span  style="white-space: nowrap; padding-left: 0px;">  {{count + ' ' + this['groupType'] | pluralize}} Selected</span>
  <a (click)="clearAll()" href="javascript:void(0);" style="padding-left: 10px;">Clear All</a>
  <button type="button" class="btn-outline btn-outline-primary" (click)="onNoClick()">Cancel</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn-width btn-sm btn-secondary" (click)="confirmModal()" [disabled]="isSaveSelectionDisabled()">Save Selection</button>
  </div>
```

### CSS

```css
.actionButtons {
  float: right;
  padding-right: 20px;
  background: white;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

Comment: Can u share a link to codepen or something?

Comment: Which version of Bootstrap are you using?

Comment: @DarrenSweeney ~3.3

Comment: @Dwayne I'd consider going to version 4 - they have flex classes in there which will do all this for you

Comment: @DarrenSweeney I wish I could :( . but bumping the version would surely blow up something else where in the project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just modified your code a bit, you can look into this:

The reason it was not working for you because you made all elements to move `right` by marking `float:right`. What I did was to make only those elements to move left and anything else towards right. hope it helps.

now you can remove your code from the `.actionButtons` it is no longer needed now.

```css
.actionButtons {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
}

#btnOutline,
#btnWidth {
  float: right;
}

#moveLeft {
  padding-top:2px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div mat-dialog-actions class="actionButtons">
  <div id="moveLeft">
    <span style="white-space: nowrap;">  Selected</span>
    <a (click)="clearAll()" href="javascript:void(0);" style="padding-left: 10px;">Clear All</a>
  </div>
  <button id="btnOutline" type="button" class="btn-outline btn-outline-primary" (click)="onNoClick()">Cancel</button>
  <button id="btnWidth" type="button" class="btn-width btn-sm btn-secondary" (click)="confirmModal()" [disabled]="isSaveSelectionDisabled()">Save Selection</button>
</div>
```

Comment: @Hey, This is causing the text on the left to move ahead line up. If you notice, text on left and text on right are not inline..

Comment: I didn't understand what inline you're talking about, I just added a border-top to make sure all 4 items are in same line looks like they're in same line.

Comment: I do not think they want to introduce a wrapping div, if they cannot control how the page content is generated.

Comment: May be, I already said I have modified the code a bit, with the OPs code it is tricky and not sure how responsiveness works!

Comment: Okay... by inline I mean. the button text on the right and text on the left should be in one line. If you run your code snippet and notice, the text on the left in little bit above if compared with text inside the buttons on the right. hope I was clear

Comment: If you see the picture in my question above... They are inline.. The only part incorrect is the text the which I  want on left(`students selected & Clear ALL`) is on the right..

Comment: I got it but it is not because of code it is because of the `font` between two elements, however I just added `padding` to make in inline, you can confirm now.

Comment: I am glad! happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to float the text to the left and keep the buttons to the right, you need to make the text elements `display:block` and float them to the left.

You will have the give the status bar a width of `100%` so that you can float the items all the way over.

I did not modify any of the existing HTML (except for changing the "Selected" text to a static value).

```css
.actionButtons {
  float: right;
  padding-right: 20px;
  background: white;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  
  /** Added */
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  text-align: right;
}

/** Added */
.actionButtons > span,
.actionButtons > a {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 1.5px; /* heights: button = 21px, text = 18px */
}
```

```html
<div mat-dialog-actions class="actionButtons">
  <span style="white-space: nowrap; padding-left: 0px;">0 Selected</span>
  <a (click)="clearAll()" href="javascript:void(0);" style="padding-left: 10px;">Clear All</a>
  <button type="button" class="btn-outline btn-outline-primary" (click)="onNoClick()">Cancel</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn-width btn-sm btn-secondary" (click)="confirmModal()" [disabled]="isSaveSelectionDisabled()">Save Selection</button>
</div>
```

Comment: @Polywhirl as per OPs requirement now your left letters is up by some 2 pixels from right side buttons.

Comment: @Manjuboyz It's actually `1.5px` (at least in Chrome). I fixed this. The items are flush with the top.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried text aligning?

```css
.actionButtons {
  float: right;
  padding-right: 20px;
  background: white;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  text-align: left; /* You may want this? */
  z-index: 100;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `float` style assigned to `actionButtons` and try this:

```css
.actionButtons * {
  float:right;
}

.actionButtons > span {
  float:left;
}
```

Comment: This is wrong, please read the question again. It's the first 2 children.